# Security Risk? $_REQUEST variables ... $$ on the local stack

Tags: php, security, variables, request, global

I was talking with one of my programmers earlier and he showed me a piece of code he was considering:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $var=>$val) {
    $$var = addslashes($val);
}
```

He wanted to be able to use `$varName` instead of having to write `$_REQUEST['varName']`

I advised him to use the `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `addSlashes` and to not put the `$_REQUEST` variables onto the local stack because that gives hackers an attach vector. To me that seems like the same problem that the old `REGISTER_GLOBALS` directive had.

He said there was not the same security risks because those variables were all being created on the local stack. So I was uncertain and I checked out the PHP variable variables page at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php but saw no reference to Super Globals and security other then the warning box.

Can hackers easily take advantage of that construct?

Comment: Looks like it's time to find a new programmer!

Comment: That is really bad from a security and design perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is like turning back 6 years of PHP security enhancements... Basically, `register_globals` and `magic_quotes` put together! Those two are marked deprecated in recent versions of PHP, and will be removed from future versions, for very good reasons.

Imagine the following code:

```
if ($is_admin) {
    do_administrative_task();
}
```

Now somebody makes the following request:

```
http://www.example.com/script.php?is_admin=1
```

And just like that, you're admin!

Likewise, `addslashes()` doesn't really provide any protections against SQL injection attacks, because it doesn't understand modern character sets. It's ridiculously easy to craft something that will bypass `addslashes()` and pwn your database.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't coded php in years, but isn't there a function that does this? Perhaps called [extract](https://www.php.net/extract)?

There are a few warnings about using that function with user inputted data.. those warnings would apply to your code snippet as well.

Answer (score 1):

The "local stack" has nothing to do with it. It still lets anyone create a new variable in some part of the code that the programmer may not have anctipated.

If he *really* wants to take the request parameters out of `$_REQUEST` and make variables of them all, then he should transfer *only* the ones the code is going to look for and no more.

And ditch `addslashes()`. That is not only the wrong place to escape incoming data, but the wrong function, too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the request URL contains `...&GLOBALS[var]=1` then it will overwrite the according global variable.

He should at least consider following construct for safety:

```
 extract($_REQUEST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "var_");  // or EXTR_SKIP
```

This will give the localized variables at least a prefix and prevent overwriting of globals. For good measure also use `array_map("addslashes", $_REQUEST)`  or a more appropriate escaping function. But really, this is just magic_quotes by another name. (Offtopic: try to let go off mysql_query and use PDO and prepared statements, which is simpler and more secure.)

Answer (score 0):

Right so!
As the programmer in question there are actually three separate issues here.

1. That `$_REQUEST` is no more insecure than `$_GET` or `$_POST` given that by default PHP `$_COOKIES` takes precedence over `$_GET` and `$_POST`.
2. Setting a superglobal's value is more secure than a local variable in a function or an object method local variable.
3. End user created variable in a function are globally accessible.

Let's start at the top.

1. `$_POST` and `$_GET` are not more secure than `$_REQUEST`. All information received from a form is dirty. Period. Regardless. If I can send in faked cookies I have the know how to fake `POST` variables. The argument is moot.
2. So we take a local variable we create with `$var.` The scope of this variable is only within the function/method. Is setting the contents of a superglobal to the value of user supplied data MORE secure than a local variable that gets scrubbed when the function/method stack gets cleaned? I wonder...
3. Lets take a snippet

```
function some_function() {
   foreach($_POST as $var=>$val) {
        $$var = $val; 
  }
}
```

Now, if `$_POST` contains a variable called `_POST` this code will set a local variable `$_POST` containing the value. However, superglobals will override this and any reference to `$_POST` will reference the superglobal, not the local variable and as such the local `$_POST` is unrefereceable. Given this functionality of PHP, without using the global keyword it is normally impossible to completely override the superglobal